# How to extract particular sublevel in deeply nested list with rapply?

Tags: r, list, extract

Out of a bunch of list I want to extract both vectors `c` and `p` and `rbind` them to a matrix.

The lists look like that:

```
List of 10
 $ :List of 2
  ..$  :List of 3
  .. ..$ c : int [1:2] 1 5
  .. ..$ x1: num [1:10] -0.565 0.363 0.633 0.404 -0.106 ...
  .. ..$ x2: num [1:10] 2.287 -1.389 -0.279 -0.133 0.636 ...
  ..$ p: int [1:10] 6 8 4 9 10 2 1 7 5 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$  :List of 3
  .. ..$ c : int [1:2] 8 2
  [...]
```

The `p`s are easy,

```
do.call(rbind, sapply(L, "[", 2))
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# p    6    8    4    9   10    2    1    7    5     3
# p    5    6    2    8    1    7    9   10    3     4
# p   10    8    1    3    9    5    6    7    4     2
# ...
```

but this method leads me to a double `sapply` for the `c`s,

```
do.call(rbind, sapply(sapply(L, `[`, 1), `[`, 1))
#   [,1] [,2]
# c    1    5
# c    8    2
# ...
```

and there might be a probably more efficient way to do that.

Now I'm puzzling with `rapply` and can't figure out how to get into the second sublevel. After looking in `` ?`[` `` for suitable arguments I only found `i`,

```
rapply(L, `[`, i=2, how="list")
```

but that trims me the sublists to their first element instead.

Is the substitute for the double `sapply` possible at all with `rapply`? How? Or maybe is there another more efficient base R solution?

BTW, after that I want to apply `colMeans`.

***Data***

```
set.seed(42)
L <- replicate(10, list(list(c=sample(10, 2), x1=rnorm(10), x2=rnorm(10)), 
                        p=sample(10, 10)), simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: What about sticking to `lapply`? `do.call(rbind, lapply(L, function(x) x[[1]]$c))`

Comment: @JdeMello Nice..same with `sapply` would be `t(sapply(L, function(x) x[[1]]$c))`

Comment: Here is an option with `map` `map(L,  ~ pluck(.x, 1)$c) %>% do.call(rbind, .)`

Comment: @RonakShah Your is more elegant, but slower than , `do.call(rbind, lapply(...))`. Nice

Comment: Confirmed, `lapply` of  @JdeMello is fastest.